# How do we dynamically add id's in onclick function taken in django?

Tags: javascript, django

I am new to django and I am having 8 cards. Every card having id,content,and image path which i had dynamically rendered from the database. Now when user clicks on one card the cards information should store in javascript object and should print on console.The code I had done upto now is

```
<div class="row">
  {% for i in room %}
    <div class="col-4">
      <div class="card6 mt-3" id="main_{{ i.id }}" style="width: 12rem;" onclick="getdata({{ i.id }})">
        <img src="{{ i.image.url }}" id="img_{{ i.id }}" alt="..." width="185" height="100">
        <div class="card-body">
          <p class="card-text" id="cont_{{ i.id }}"><b>{{ i.content }}</b></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  {% endfor %}
</div>
```

IN JAVASCRIPT I had written the onclick get data function

```
var object= [];
function getData(id,image,content)
  {
     var id = id;
     var image= $("#img_"+id).attr('src');
     var content = $("#cont_"+id).text();
     console.log('id', id)
     console.log('image', image)
     console.log('content', content)
  }
});
```

Still I am getting error like **project1:77 Uncaught ReferenceError: getdata is not defined
    at HTMLDivElement.onclick (** Please see if any errors in the code and help me out

Comment: The error says that the `getdata` function you attached on `onclick` is not found. Have you included the Javascript file where you wrote this function in HTML?

Comment: Yes I had included all other functions that I have written on cards are working

Comment: @G.Lakshmi getdata != getData. In your html, the function name should be getData

Comment: @NalinDobhal its just a mistake when i asking the question those are matched but the error is same

Comment: Debug the Javascript in Browser, put a break point on this function and see if it is getting called

Comment: Actually is it correct in django onclick=getData({{i.id}}) is this parsing correct because it is showing error in editor I am not understanding can you please help me out.

Comment: i think you supposed to put the function in double quote `onclick="getData({{i.id}})"` [source](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onclick.asp)

Comment: @Linh Nguygen I had kept

Answer (score 0):

```
var object= [];
function getdata(id,image,content)
  {
     var id = id;
     var image= $("#img_"+id).attr('src');
     var content = $("#cont_"+id).text();
     console.log('id', id)
     console.log('image', image)
     console.log('content', content)
  }
});
```

change JS function name with all lower case